# Manually created SMS refuses to appear

Tags: android, save, sms, manual

I've been trying to manually store an SMS but for some unknown reason. It doesn't show. I've tried many example codes and edited the manifest file as told. Not even this, (which is the most popular answer I found)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", "123456789");
    values.put("body", "foo bar");
    getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the logs after this is ran for any hint of what may going wrong? Also what version are you running on?

Comment: Actually.. I'm developing on an app called AIDE... Not sure if logs are even available

Comment: Yes they are. Menu => View... => LogCat. Or just swipe the lower pane all the way to the right.

Comment: OK.. I'll see what's up

Comment: What version of Android are you running?

Comment: The android version is 4.4.2...

Comment: OK... I've seen the reason for this.. Ill edit my code in relation to this..